# how we save logs of our application actions in mongodb(node.js) with one schema and limited information

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, logging

I am working on a node js with MongoDB database we want to logs of our application action with limited information like success, action name, user id, time, etc so how we can do this in node js with MongoDB

Comment: I would also propose you to take a look, maybe it's better for small projects to save it locally.

Answer (score 0):

You can look in the official website of mongo how to do it [Mongo Logs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/log-messages/), and if you want a custom one just create a new db/collection to put in your logs and send it as a regular request.